# ESRI web scene does not load in Story Map Journal

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map, embeddable-web-maps, web-scene, http

The web scene I'm trying to embed into my Journal will only load when I'm logged in (be it while I'm in editing mode or if viewing it from another tab). If opening the story in another web-browser or computer, I see the loading bars for a second or so then they disappear and nothing happens. I've read many posts about scenes not loading within a Story Journal due to HTTPS vs HTTP and shared/unshared issues. Reading over those, I've followed the advice but to no avail.

Here are the details of my organization, Journal and web scene in question, maybe someone can spot the issue:

- I've checked that the browsers support WebGL
- In my account profile, my organization URL includes HTTPS (https://UTEP.maps.arcgis.com)
- The Journal and web scene are both shared publicly.
- The Journal URL includes HTTPs as per the it's settings page ( https://utep.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapJournal/index.html?appid=c2b657d045a04df89fd5911e6178b71c )
- The Web scene url includes HTTPs ( https://utep.maps.arcgis.com/home/webscene/viewer.html?webscene=cac10a51b6414913a672559032dd1573&ui=min )
- In the configuration of the web scene url for the main stage, I leave "unload when reader navigates away" uncheck and by default, "Load page over a secure connection (HTTPs)" is checked.
- The page that is supposed to have the scene embedded is the second after the home page (for those attempting to check it out)
- Not sure if this is anything, but ever since I started trying to embedded the web scene and playing around with it, the usage of the underlying scene layer has skyrocketed (I'm talking ~8,000 requests in the past five days).

Is this normal or could it be contributing to the problem?

Is there a request every single time I pan, tilt or zoom around?

Comment: Looks like you solved it? Love the RGB Point Cloud dataset!

Comment: Thanks! That’s my study site, I’m looking at coastal erosion in the Arctic. Anyways, yes I figured it out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. My I had to strip “utep.maps” (organization prefix)  from the beginning of the web scene url before embedding for some reason.